# input validation loop is not working properly after the 1st failed input

Tags: c++

so this works good at catching the 1st invalid input but once they make 1 bad input the correct ones don't work anymore either. If they input c, C, s, or S the 1st time it works fine but on the 2nd try it doesn't EX: 1st attempt the user inputs p then it asks them to try again, 2nd attempt they input c it asks them to try again.

```
cout << "Checking (C) or Savings (S): enter your choice" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    while(choice != 'c' && choice != 'C' && choice != 's' && choice != 'S')
        {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
```

how can I i fix this?

Comment: Take a look at the loop again - do you see any attempt to read anything inside it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the condition for your input validation loop:

```
while(choice != 'c' && choice != 'C' && choice != 's' && choice != 'S')
    {
```

You don't touch the value of `choice` inside this loop, so if the execution winds up in the loop once, there's no way out. Simply remember to actually get a new value for `choice` inside the loop to avoid this issue.

Comment: thanks i just plugged in a cin >> choice; at the bottom and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to redo the input:

```
 while (!(std::cin >> choice) || (choice != 'c' && choice != 'C' && choice != 's' && choice != 'S'))
```